# weird behaviour on negative value in currentcy fields ( namespace issue? )

Tags: namespace, currencytype

Salesforce currency field allow negative value input. When you are on the environment with namespace it will convert negative amount to number with brackets( exp. (11) ) however when you are working on the environment without name space it doesn't put the bracket but normal value -11.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Check your user Locale on your user detail (Setup > My Personal Information > Personal Information), and make sure they are the same. Different locales display currency differently.

Comment: both environments are english(canada). I do google but nobody can have negative sign for currency field(display with brackets) but on my environment without namespace I can see the negative sign.

Comment: Sorry I found out it was Currency Locale on the company profile not the namespace https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205692&language=en_US

Comment: Can you add some more details? Where does the currency show up like that? Record detail view? Reports? Apex calculation?

Comment: When displaying the currency field in apext page with apex:inputfield or apex:outputfield.